# Swipeable React-native-modal with nested ScrollView

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-modal

I'm using the latest [release](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal/releases) of [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) that implement the [swipe feature](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal/pull/105)

I'd like to add a ScrollView inside my modal.

Here's what i've done so far

https://snack.expo.io/ryRylJFHz

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I know that this question is old but since there isn't an answer I am providing a solution to this.

The latest version of `react-native-modal` provides a prop `propagateSwipe` that allows swipe events to propagate to child components in your case to `ScrollView`

```
<Modal propagateSwipe={true}> 
    <ScrollView> 
       // .... other components
    </ScrollView>
<Modal>
```

But currently in the `v11.3.1` it has a small issue when you provide `swipeDirection` prop and it doesn't work.

The workaround to this issue is to add `TouchableOpacity` component inside `ScrollView`. Also adding `activeOpacity={1}` removes opacity change animation on press.

```
<Modal> 
    <ScrollView> 
         <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}> ... </TouchableOpacity> 
    </ScrollView>
<Modal>
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal/issues/236) about this issue.

Comment: By using TouchableOpacity, scroll on ScrollView worked perfectly

Comment: Yes, adding any touchable resolves the issue.

Comment: [example](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal/blob/master/example/src/modals/ScrollableModal.tsx)

Comment: Setting propagateSwipe worked like a charm !!!

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue multiple of times where I needed to add a scrollview, and none of the packages out there were doing it well. In reality, handling swiping and scrolling events are more complicated than expected.

I came up with creating a component to handle the scrollview behavior by default and others behaviors that are really common. You can check it here, it's called [react-native-modalize](https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize)

Hope it will solve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by Defining a fixed height for the scrollview container.

For E.g

```
<View style={{height: 300}}>
   {hasResults ? (
       <ScrollView>
         ....
       </ScrollView>
    ) : undefined}
</View>
```

According to official react native docs scrollview should have a bounded height to work.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview

`Keep in mind that ScrollViews must have a bounded height in order to work, since they contain unbounded-height children into a bounded container (via a scroll interaction). In order to bound the height of a ScrollView, either set the height of the view directly (discouraged) or make sure all parent views have bounded height. Forgetting to transfer {flex: 1} down the view stack can lead to errors here, which the element inspector makes quick to debug.`